# Codigo en python 3.5 me devuelve cálculos erróneos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Saludos!

Estoy empezanvdo con Python 3.5. He escrito este código y no tengo ni idea de porqué no funciona, la versión de este código en 2.7 funciona pero al pasar a 3.5 no y sospecho que es por algo del manejo de número en esta versión. Da igual que pulses "h" que pulses "l", te devuelve siempre lo mismo..

Es un codigo que intenta "adivinar" qué número has pensado (del curso de edx).

```
lowest = 0
highest = 100
guess = 50

while True:
    print("Is your secret number %d?" %(guess))
    answer = str(input('Enter \'h\' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter \'l\' to indicate the guess is too low.'
                       ' Enter \'c\' to indicate I guessed correctly. '))
    if answer == "h":
        highest = guess - 1
        guess = (highest - lowest)/2
    elif answer == "l":
        lowest = guess + 1
        guess = (highest - lowest)/2
    elif answer == "c":
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")

print("Game over. Your secret number was: %d" %(guess))
```

Gracias y saludos a todos!

Comment: Bienvenido! Te invito a pasar por el [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta.
Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Si te funciona en 2.7 y no en 3.5, podrías portar usando `2to3`, un programa para pasar código de python 2.x a 3.x. [Acá](http://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com.ar/2015/01/convertir-programas-python-2x-3x.html) una explicación de como usarlo.

Comment: Publica el error que te aparece, porque yo lo acabo de ejecutar el código y no marco ningún error. No adivinó el número, y le puse `c` por lástima, pero probé `h`y `l` sin problemas.

Comment: Hola gracias a todos! el 2to3 me será muy util! muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existen unas cuantas diferencias entre Python 2.x y Python 3.x. En general, si estás empezando, deberías usar Python 3.x a no ser que tengas un requerimiento especial para hacerlo en Python 2.x. Yendo al código, existen varias diferencias que hacen que el código actúe diferente.

En Python 3.x la división entre enteros funciona como se esperaría, en cambio, en Python 2.x, la división entre enteros devuelve la parte entera del resultado:

```
# Python 2.x
>>> print(1/2)
0

# Python 3.x
>>> print(1/2)
0.5
```

Para hacer que la división en Python 2.x funcione como se esperaría se puede convertir uno de los números de la división en decimal o se puede importar la funcionalidad de división tal como funciona en Python 3.x:

```
# Python 2.x (opción a)
>>> print(1./2) # print(1/2.)
0.5

# Python 2.x (opción b)
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> print(1/2)
0.5
```

En Python 3.x, para hacer una división entre enteros y que el resultado sea un entero se puede usar el operador `//`:

```
# Python 3.x
>>> print(1//2)
0
```

Por otra parte, en Python 2.x existen `input` y `raw_input`. El primero evalúa la expresión que insertes pudiendo ejecutar código con todo el peligro que conlleva que permitas que un usuario pueda ejecutar código. Es por ello que en Python 3.x se eliminó `input` y `raw_input` se renombró como `ínput`. De esta forma, en Python 3.x solo tienes disponible `input` que funciona como `raw_input` en Python 2.x. Por tanto, si estás en Python 2.x nunca jamás uses `input` a no ser que sepas lo que estás haciendo y tengas buenos motivos para ello.

Cosas específicas de tu código, cuando usas comillas o dobles comillas no es necesario 'escapar' las comillas como cuando haces `'\'h\''`. Puedes combinar tanto comillas como dobles comillas siempre que seas consistente. Por ejemplo, lo siguiente es válido:

```
print("Hola, 'estoy entrecomillado'.")
```

Si abres y cierras con dobles comillas puedes usar comillas en tu cadena. Lo mismo sucede si abres y cierras con comillas y usas dobles comillas en tu cadena:

```
print('Hola, "estoy entrecomillado".')
```

Pero si las mezclas te llevará a errores.

Yendo a tu código, a mi no me funciona ni en Python 2.x ni en Python 3.x y cómo estás usando cosas diferentes es normal que no actúe igual. Manteniedo el código como el que has escrito (y haciéndolo compatible con Python 2.x y 3.x) se podría hacer lo siguiente:

```
from __future__ import division # para que la división actúe igual en ambas versiones
import sys

# Esto lo hacemos para saber qué input vamos a usar en ambas versiones
# creamos un alias para saber lo que estamos usando y no meter condiciones
# en medio del código
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    my_input = input
else:
    my_input = raw_input

lowest = 0
highest = 100
guess = 50

while True:
    print("Is your secret number %d?" %(guess))
    answer = my_input('Enter "h" to indicate the guess is too high.'
                      ' Enter "l" to indicate the guess is too low.'
                      ' Enter "c" to indicate I guessed correctly.')
    if answer == "h":
        highest = guess
        guess = highest - (highest - lowest) // 2 # este es un error en tu algoritmo
    elif answer == "l":
        lowest = guess
        guess = lowest + (highest - lowest) // 2 # este es un error en tu algoritmo
    elif answer == "c":
        print("Game over. Your secret number was: %d" %(guess))
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
```

Lo ideal sería usar limitar también el valor del valor que puede introducir el usuario pero eso ya te lo dejo a ti.

Comment: Efectivamente hay un error en el algortimo ^^U. ¡De todas formas si que tengo que utilizar la división "antigua" (la 2.7) para evitar que me queden decimales en algun paso! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: El código que he dejado funciona igual en Python 2.x y Python 3.x por lo que te vale para ambas versiones.

Answer (score 3):

**Python** es un lenguaje nuevo para mí, pero estoy aprendiendo.

Estuve probando el código y no funciona en la versión **2.7** porque, al parecer `input` tiene ciertos problemas, en su lugar se debe usar `raw_input`. [►](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input)

```py
#Versión 2.7
lowest = 0
highest = 100
guess = 50


while True:
    print("Is your secret number %d?" %(guess))

    answer = raw_input('Enter \'h\' to indicate the guess is too high. '
                       'Enter \'l\' to indicate the guess is too low. '
                       'Enter \'c\' to indicate I guessed correctly. ')

    if answer == 'h':
        highest = guess - 1
        guess = (lowest + highest) / 2
    elif answer == "l":
        lowest = guess + 1
        guess = (lowest + highest) / 2
    elif answer == "c":
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")

print("Game over. Your secret number was: %d" %(guess))
```

En cambio en la versión **3.5**, el que tiene problemas es `raw_input`, y se debe usar `input`. [►](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/2to3.html?highlight=raw_input#2to3fixer-raw_input)

Se ve que les cuesta ponerse de acuerdo, pero de todas formas sigue siendo un lenguaje interesante.

```py
#Versión 3.5
lowest = 0
highest = 100
guess = 50


while True:
    print("Is your secret number %d?" %(guess))

    answer = input('Enter \'h\' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter \'l\' to indicate the guess is too low.'
                       ' Enter \'c\' to indicate I guessed correctly. ')

    if answer == 'h':
        highest = guess - 1
        guess = (lowest + highest) // 2
        print ("lowest = %i highest = %i" %(lowest,highest))
    elif answer == "l":
        lowest = guess + 1
        guess = (lowest + highest) // 2
        print ("lowest = %i highest = %i" %(lowest,highest))
    elif answer == "c":
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")

print("Game over. Your secret number was: %d" %(guess))
```

Otra novedad que encontré es que, mientras la versión **2.7** devuelve un `int` al dividir, la versión **3.5** devuelve un `float`, por lo que se debe usar el operador de división entera, que es `//`. [►](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers)

Otro detalle: para que el programa funcione, en lugar de restar, se deben **sumar** las variables `lowest` y `highest`.

Comment: Efectivamente hay que sumar las variables y no restarlas ^^. ¡De todas formas si que tengo que utilizar la división "antigua" (la 2.7) para evitar que me queden decimales! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.